# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1979711488) (tried to allocate 131072 bytes) error occur while writing xlsx file using phpexcel

Tags: php, out-of-memory, phpexcel, ini, xlsx

I have integrating xlsx file for writing from database using phpexcel. I want to write 3,00,000 records in xlsx file. But it till through **Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1979711488) (tried to allocate 131072 bytes)**

My PHP Version 5.3.28

Also i set php ini and cell cache see my code below

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',-1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); 
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_in_memory_gzip;
$cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '-1');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
```

I'm looking forward for your reply.

Thanks

Comment: Did you remember to restart (or reload) apache / nginx after your changes??

Comment: You need to restart / reload your web service in order to these changes to take effect :)

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have? 1979711488 bytes is almost 2gb of ram usage.

Comment: Gzipped in memory isn't the best caching method for large spreadsheet files - use the method that gives the best memory saving - typically using SQLite - if possible - [memory usage / PHP Version comparisons](http://imgur.com/3GuYsLi)

Comment: The chart I've linked in my comment above, and the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md) show all the available caching options, and give an indication of which provide the best memory reductions based on the PHP Version that you're using

Comment: @MarkBaker i set **PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_sqlite** Now through **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6 bytes)**

Comment: In that case you might need to up memory a bit from that 1GB to the 2GB That you originally had; caching reduces memory usage, it doesn't eliminate it.... but also test the `PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod()` call, because it will revert to using normal PHP memory on fail.... and SQLite was typically dropped in favour of SQLite3 with PHP >= 5.4.0

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to write a very large amount of records, it may be possible that even if you use the caching techniques PHPExcel provides, you'd still encounter OutOfMemory errors. Or that your script would take too long to finish (too long to be acceptable).

If this is something you see happening, I can recommend you taking a look at [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout): https://github.com/box/spout. It's an alternative to PHPExcel that was created to solve exactly your problem. You can throw it as many records as you want, the library will be able to write them without needing any extra config.

Writing a XLSX file is that easy:

```
$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$writer->openToFile($filePath);

while (...) {
    $writer->addRow($singleRow);
}

$writer->close();
```