# Using PHP to fetch from Oracle into Excelsheet using PHPExcel, with data more then 65k row?

Tags: php, oracle, phpexcel, oracle-call-interface, prefetch

I'm using PHP OCI8 to retrieve data from oracle database into MS Excel Spreadsheet by using PHP Excel Function. The data consist of 23 column and more then 65k row. I consider this as big data and its fail to write to Excel and showing this error

> Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 900 seconds exceeded in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php on line 1058

1. My question is how to calculate the right amount of time needed with the data that Im extracting?
2. What is the best practice of extracting this large data into Spreadsheet or CSV file?

in the code is already set `oci_set_prefetch($stid1, 400);` and if data less then 65k the system will allow to write to the file (`.xls`)

Comment: See if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24481241/460557 teaches how to increase the Maximum execution

Comment: Best advice is to run large data extracts as a background process, not from the Web SAPI..... your code may also be inefficient, but we can't comment on that as we can't see it

Comment: But if you can use a CSV file, then use that instead with PHP's fputcsv() function.... if the data equates to a single worksheet, and you don't need any of the formatting or other features of MS Excel, then it's a lot more efficient

Comment: Mark Baker - I'm planning to request user to download the data by themself, some of them doesn't know how to view the CSV data in Excel. Is there any possibility I can write again the CSV file format onto Excel Spreadsheet.

Comment: MS Excel will happily import a csv file, either via its import menu option, or by double-clicking on the csv file to open it

Comment: If you still want to export an Excel file, you can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32890264/4499987